# How can I update my 'subset' in the MongoDb Subset pattern?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I'm fairly new to mongodb.  Reading about the subset pattern, I think it makes sense for my use case, however I'm not seeing much guidance on how to cleanly keep the subset up to date.

Taking the example they give, if I have a Blog object and a subset of comments, and a user adds a new comment, Do i then need to make a secondary call to update the blog object?  Can I do that all in one query?

For context, i'm using dotnet + linq.